# Using ES6 spread notation is overriding inside the new obj

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have two objects.

```
const resolver = {
  Query: {
    hi() {
      return 'Hello Level Up';
    }
  }
};

const resolver2 = {
  Query: {
    resolutions() {
      return [
        {
          _id: 'alksdfaqwef231adsf2',
          name: 'Get stuff done!'
        },
        {
          _id: 'wefqwefasdf',
          name: 'Get stuff done 2!'
        }
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

Whenever I do something like:

```
const resolvers = { ...resolver, ...resolver2 };
```

The first resolver gets overridden and I only have this if I console.log

```
{ Query: { resolutions: [Function: resolutions] } }
```

I want it to have:

```
{ Query: { hi: [Function: hi], resolutions: [Function: resolutions] } }
```

Comment: Yes, it does that by design. What is the question?

Comment: What did you expect would happen?

Comment: do you maybe want? `const resolvers = { resolver, resolver2 };`

Comment: it is working the way it should work.

Comment: the spread operator just works in the first level of the objet, so it just see the 'Query' property and nothing else

Comment: Let me add what I want it to do sorry about that.

Comment: I made the edit if you could look

Comment: `const resolvers = { Query: {  ...resolver.Query, ...resolver2.Query } }`

Comment: I found a lodash method im going to use called merge I think. seems to be a lot more simple and keeps both functions as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was already mentioned, but that is how spread operator works. To do a deep merge, you'll need to write a recursive method yourself. Or use a very popular small library called [deepmerge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge).

In your case this will work though:

```
const resolvers = { 
  Query: {
    ...resolver.Query,
    ...resolver2.Query
  } 
};
```

Comment: This absolutely works and im going to give you the answer since I was asking how to do it in ES6, but I ended up using lodash instead.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem I brought in a package called `lodash` and used the `merge` method.

```
const resolvers = merge(resolver, resolver2);
```

outputs:

```
{ Query: { hi: [Function: hi], resolutions: [Function: resolutions] } }
```

Comment: lodash is such a great library for this kind of stuff.